# Highlight Button in Webpage If Login User Has not Clicked On

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Looking for a way to highlight buttons that the User has not visited in case of changes the content of the views that are redirected when these buttons are clicked. The solution should be in the ASP.net MVC CSS framework.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">

 body{
     overflow-x:scroll;
 }
    .auto-stylelay1 {
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: left;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</head>
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand" style="font-size: 22px">
                <a href="#">
                    <strong>
                </strong>
                </a>
            </li>
         <b></b>
                <p class="auto-style2"><strong>Hello @User.Identity.Name!</strong></p> 
                <li class="auto-stylelay1">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li class="auto-stylelay1">@Html.ActionLink("Proof of Concept", "POC", "Home")</li>
                <li class="auto-stylelay1">@Html.ActionLink("Reports", "report", "Home")</li>
                <li class="auto-stylelay1">@Html.ActionLink("Links/Other Resources", "Links", "Home")</li>
                <li class="auto-stylelay1">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li class="auto-stylelay1">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I would like to change the layout style page buttons for the menu bar in case the user has not clicked. I have added a check to see where the user has browsed. As well as the date they have browsed in. But I am missing the code to do changes to the shared layout file per user.

I expect the button to be highlighted with some new content indicator. Basically I want to change class styles for the li html action links depending on whether the user visited this page or not. If the button is clicked I want to return the class to auto-stylelay1.

Comment: share your code

Comment: And you will want all the buttons highlighed then remove highlight after buttons are clicked.

Comment: People are putting their time into this trying to help you. Please look at the answer I provided and let me know if that helps you

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to save it in the local storage.

**First assign an id to each list item:**

```
<li id="Home" class="auto-stylelay1">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
<li id="POC" class="auto-stylelay1">@Html.ActionLink("Proof of Concept", "POC", "Home")</li>
<li id="Reports" class="auto-stylelay1">@Html.ActionLink("Reports", "report", "Home")</li>
```

**If a button is clicked add it to an array and save it to the local storage:**

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // stop following link

   var retrievedDate = localStorage.getItem("buttonsClicked");
   var buttonsClicked = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
   var elementId = $(this).attr('id') // Get Id of element
   buttonsClicked.push(elementId);
   localStorage.setItem("buttonsClicked", JSON.stringify(buttonsClicked.push)); // save back
   window.location = $(this).attr('href'); // now follow link
});
```

**Now on view load you have to read and see which ones have been pressed:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var retrievedDate = localStorage.getItem("buttonsClicked");
   var buttonsClicked = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
   // loop through array
   buttonsClicked.each(function (index, value) {
       $("#"+value).addClass("auto-stylelay1");
   });
});
```

You can place the script inside the _Layout view.
Note: I haven't tested this. Let me know if it worked.